# Variable Reluctance Machines - what does the 6/4 or the 8/6 values mean?

Tags: motor

I have been reading about electrical machines and keep getting these values in the examples but can't find what they actually mean. Is the first number the amount of stator poles and the second number is the rotor poles?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Post more context, please, if possible.  Excerpts, perhaps.  If you were reading on the web, post links.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the first number is the number of stator poles and the second number is the number of rotor poles.

Comment: This does answer the question directly, but we usually look for a little more from answers here than a single sentence.

Comment: I understand that most questions require more than a single sentence but I didn't really feel it was necessary in this case.  Even now I'm struggling to figure out what else I could add to my answer.  But if you have any suggestions, I will gladly edit it.